# jQuery Click is executing multiple times

Tags: jquery, events, click

Consider the following code.

```
$(function(){

    $(".notes").click(function(){
        console.log('hi');          
    })
})

    <a data-shipmentid="1" href="#" class="notes btn btn-primary btn-xs">Notes</a>
    <a data-shipmentid="1" href="#" class="notes btn btn-primary btn-xs">Notes</a>
    <a data-shipmentid="1" href="#" class="notes btn btn-primary btn-xs">Notes</a>
    <a data-shipmentid="1" href="#" class="notes btn btn-primary btn-xs">Notes</a>
    <a data-shipmentid="1" href="#" class="notes btn btn-primary btn-xs">Notes</a>
```

The purpose is to log a message when any of the hyperlink is clicked. The issue I am facing is that if I click on a hyperlink, then the console it getting the message "hi" 5 times ( the total number of hyperlinks with the class "notes" )

I understand that something is wrong. How do I check what is wrong here in this case? I see console is not displaying any error messages. Anyone has any idea why the event is firing up multiple times?

Comment: that should only be done once - can you reproduce in a fiddle or snippet?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it should only execute once. And I can't reproduce it on JsFiddle( I tried that ) with the same code that I am using on my project ( which is a large project ). I need some suggestions on where to look for possible errors

Comment: I also tried to upgrade jQuery from 1.10 to 1.11 thinking that it may be the issue with jquery core, but it isn't

Comment: we can't help you without a more complete picture.

Comment: See what gets selected with `console.log($(".notes"))`

Comment: It is displaying object which has <a> tag 5 times. And this object is displayed 5 times.

Comment: Screenshot http://postimg.org/image/l2epmk2p5/ and expanded the first object http://postimg.org/image/xbr0qrcj1/

Comment: You can always try `$(".notes").off().click...`

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by Shanimal worked!

```
$(function(){
 $(".notes").off().click(function(){
    console.log('hi');          
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

How about use .one()

```
$(function(){

    $(".notes").one('click', function(){
        console.log('hi');          
    })
})
```